# Windows task manager clone

Tags: c++, qt

I have made a clone of windows task manger using QT and c++. When I started out this project I had much less knowledge of c++ then I do know so the style of some parts of the code are not always consistent with others. the full source code can be found here https://github.com/qwertybomb/Task-Manager-Clone. However My main concern with the code is that it is not efficient, which is necessary since the program does no want to skew the results of monitoring and that it is not able to measure individual process cpu usage.
here is the code
mainwindow.h

```
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QEvent>
#include "qcustomplot.h"
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <QString>
#include "Processitem.h"
#include <cstddef>
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include<windows.h>
#include<memory>
#define gb (1024.0*1024.0*1024.0)
#define mb (1024.0*1024.0)
#define kb (1024.0)

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

 enum Computer_device{
    Memory,Cpu
 };

private:

void draw(long double , Computer_device );
void processDraw(long double , Computer_device );

void add_sample(QVector<double>&,double item);

void get_mem(std::byte* = nullptr);
void getProcess_mem(std::byte* = nullptr);

void get_cpuClock(std::byte* = nullptr);
void getProcess_cpuClock(std::byte* = nullptr);




double get_mem_val();



void reset_sampleRate(Computer_device type);

void do_test();

void processResource();

private:


QVector<Process> device_processes;
void getProcessInfo(DWORD processID,Process& old);
auto updateProcessInfo();
QTreeWidget* processInfoTree;
void updateProcessInfoTree();
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> selectedItems;
bool selectedItemsInUse = false;

private:
QComboBox* process_ComboBox;
Process currentProcess = Process("",0,0,0,QIcon(QPixmap(5,5)));
std::map<QString,double> processMax_MemoryUsage;


void updateProcessComboBox();





private:
    enum  SortMode{
        NameSortAZ, MemorySortAZ, CpuSortAZ, ProcessIDSortAZ, NameSortZA,MemorySortZA, CpuSortZA, ProcessIDSortZA,NoSort
    };
    SortMode currentSortMode= SortMode::NoSort;

private:

QTimer* m_timer;

double time_value = 0.0;
double compare_sample = 0.0;


unsigned char stayOnTop = 0;



private:

    QVector<QVector<double>> device_samples;
    QVector<QVector<double>> process_samples;

    std::thread backround;
    int clocks = 0;

private slots:

void Update();






void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1);

void on_actionStay_on_top_triggered();

void on_actionStay_on_top_toggled(bool arg1);

void on_pushButton_clicked();

void on_actionSave_as_triggered();

void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

void tableHeader_clicked(int column);

private:

QLabel* resourceUsageLabel;

std::byte currentResourceUsage;

private:


    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QCustomPlot* customPlot;
    QCustomPlot* processCustomPlot;

    int sample_time = 30000;

    int mem_sampleRate = 10000;
   
    int cpu_sampleRate =  100;

    int cpu_SamplingRate = 100;

  


   //QVector<double> samples = QVector<double>(sampleRate); // initialize with entries 0..100
   QVector<double>  x = QVector<double>(mem_sampleRate);
    QVector<double> multi_sample= QVector<double>();
   MEMORYSTATUSEX statex{};

Computer_device current_device;

unsigned long long total_ram = 0;
long long total_cpuClock = 4*gb;


//image stuff
private:

QImage m_plot;

bool imageIsSafe =false;

bool capture_plot = 0;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include "TCHAR.h"
#include "pdh.h"
#include <psapi.h>

#include <QFileDialog>
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <QtAlgorithms>
#include <QtMath>
#include <QtWin>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>


#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
#endif

static float CalculateCPULoad(unsigned long long idleTicks,
                              unsigned long long totalTicks) {
  static unsigned long long _previousTotalTicks = 0;
  static unsigned long long _previousIdleTicks = 0;

  unsigned long long totalTicksSinceLastTime = totalTicks - _previousTotalTicks;
  unsigned long long idleTicksSinceLastTime = idleTicks - _previousIdleTicks;

  float ret =
      1.0F - ((totalTicksSinceLastTime > 0)
                  ? ((float)idleTicksSinceLastTime) / totalTicksSinceLastTime
                  : 0);

  _previousTotalTicks = totalTicks;
  _previousIdleTicks = idleTicks;
  return ret;
}

static unsigned long long FileTimeToInt64(const FILETIME &ft) {
  return (((unsigned long long)(ft.dwHighDateTime)) << 32) |
         ((unsigned long long)ft.dwLowDateTime);
}

// Returns 1.0f for "CPU fully pinned", 0.0f for "CPU idle", or somewhere in
// between You'll need to call this at regular intervals, since it measures the
// load between the previous call and the current one.  Returns -1.0 on error.
float GetCPULoad() {
  FILETIME idleTime;
  FILETIME kernelTime;
  FILETIME userTime;
  return GetSystemTimes(&idleTime, &kernelTime, &userTime)
             ? CalculateCPULoad(FileTimeToInt64(idleTime),
                                FileTimeToInt64(kernelTime) +
                                    FileTimeToInt64(userTime))
             : -1.0F;
}

DWORD getParentPID(DWORD pid) {
  HANDLE h = nullptr;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,{0,0}};
  DWORD ppid = 0;
  pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
  h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if (Process32First(h, &pe)) {
    do {
      if (pe.th32ProcessID == pid) {
        ppid = pe.th32ParentProcessID;
        break;
      }
    } while (Process32Next(h, &pe));
  }
  CloseHandle(h);
  return (ppid);
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);


  customPlot = ui->tab;
 processCustomPlot = ui->tab_3;
  ui->tabWidget->setTabText(0, "Performance");
  ui->tabWidget->setTabText(1, "Processes");
  ui->tabWidget->setTabText(2, "Process performance");

  resourceUsageLabel = ui->label_2;
  customPlot->addGraph();
  processCustomPlot->addGraph();
  processInfoTree = ui->treeWidget;
  process_ComboBox = ui->comboBox_2;
  process_ComboBox->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox::AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon);

  // set selection mode
  processInfoTree->setSelectionMode(
      QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode::ExtendedSelection);
  // setup headers
  processInfoTree->setColumnCount(4);

  QList<QString> headers{QString("Name"), QString("Memory"), QString("Cpu"),
                         QString("ProcessId")};
  QTreeWidgetItem *headerItem =
      new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidgetItem *)nullptr, headers);
  headerItem->setSelected(true);
  processInfoTree->setHeaderItem(headerItem);
  // keep window on top
  setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint |
                 Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

  /*connect slot functions*/
  connect(ui->treeWidget->header(), SIGNAL(sectionDoubleClicked(int)), this,
          SLOT(tableHeader_clicked(int)));

  // update it the first frame so there is not a small time where it is blank
  updateProcessInfoTree();

  // get total memory

  statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);

  GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);

  total_ram = statex.ullTotalPhys;

  // fill samples

  double current_memValue =
      (((double)total_ram - (double)statex.ullAvailPhys) / gb);

  // set enum
  current_device = Memory;
  backround = std::thread();

  // set up device sample vectors
  device_samples.push_back(QVector<double>(mem_sampleRate, current_memValue));
  device_samples.push_back(
      QVector<double>(cpu_sampleRate, GetCPULoad() * 100.0));


  process_samples.push_back(QVector<double>(mem_sampleRate, 0));
  process_samples.push_back(
      QVector<double>(cpu_sampleRate, GetCPULoad() * 100.0));

  // set up vars

  // set up timer

  m_timer = new QTimer(this);

  QTimer::singleShot(1, this, SLOT(Update()));

  m_timer->start(1);

  for (int i = 0; i < mem_sampleRate; ++i) {
    x[i] = ((double)i / (mem_sampleRate));
  }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

void MainWindow::draw(long double top, Computer_device type) {

  QVector<double> samples = device_samples[type];

  // create graph and assign data to it:

  QColor a;
  a.setRgb(160, 3, 170, 70);

  customPlot->graph()->setBrush(a);
  customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, samples);

  // give the axes some labels:
  customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("Total Use");
  customPlot->xAxis->setTicks(false);

  // set axes ranges, so we see all data:
  customPlot->xAxis->setRange(0.0, 1.0);
  customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0.0, top);
  customPlot->replot();

  if (capture_plot) {
    m_plot = customPlot->toPixmap(this->width(), this->height()).toImage();

    capture_plot = false;
  }

  multi_sample.clear();
}

void MainWindow::processDraw(long double top, Computer_device type)
{

    QVector<double> samples = process_samples[type];

    // create graph and assign data to it:

    QColor a;
    a.setRgb(160, 3, 170, 70);

    processCustomPlot->graph()->setBrush(a);
    processCustomPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, samples);

    // give the axes some labels:
    processCustomPlot->yAxis->setLabel("Total Use");
    processCustomPlot->xAxis->setTicks(false);

    // set axes ranges, so we see all data:
    processCustomPlot->xAxis->setRange(0.0, 1.0);
    processCustomPlot->yAxis->setRange(0.0, top);
    processCustomPlot->replot();
    if (capture_plot) {
      m_plot = processCustomPlot->toPixmap(this->width(), this->height()).toImage();

      capture_plot = false;
    }

}

void MainWindow::add_sample(QVector<double> &vec, double item) {
  item = abs(item);

  vec.pop_back();

  vec.insert(0, item);
}

/*
 *   sample = sin(time/2.0)*0.5+0.5;
 *  sample *= total_ram/gb;
 * double time = (double)QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay()/1000.0;
 */

// get memory
void MainWindow::get_mem(std::byte *currentValue) {

  double sample = 0;

  GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);

  sample = double(total_ram - statex.ullAvailPhys) / gb;
  if (currentValue != nullptr) {
    *currentValue = static_cast<std::byte>(
        round((total_ram - statex.ullAvailPhys) / double(total_ram) * 100.0));
  }

  add_sample(device_samples[0], sample);
}

void MainWindow::getProcess_mem(std::byte *currentValue)
{
    double sample = 0;
    if(device_processes.empty()){return;}


    sample = double(currentProcess.memoryUsage());
    if (currentValue != nullptr) {
      *currentValue = static_cast<std::byte>(
          round((total_ram - statex.ullAvailPhys) / double(processMax_MemoryUsage[currentProcess.name()]) * 100.0));
    }

    add_sample(process_samples[0], sample);
}

void MainWindow::getProcessInfo(DWORD processID, Process &old) {

  TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

  // Get a handle to the process.

  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
  _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc{};

  old.SetId(processID);
  // Print the process identifier.

  // Get the process name.

  if (nullptr != hProcess) {

    HMODULE hMod;
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded)) {

      GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                        sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    }
    
    if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&pmc,
                             sizeof(pmc))) {

      old.SetmemoryUsage(pmc.PrivateUsage / (mb));
    };

    auto temp = QString::fromUtf16((const ushort *)szProcessName);
    old.Setname(temp);

   if(processMax_MemoryUsage.find(temp)!=processMax_MemoryUsage.end())
   {
        if(old.memoryUsage() > processMax_MemoryUsage[temp])
        processMax_MemoryUsage[temp]=old.memoryUsage()*1.25;
   }
   else
   {
       processMax_MemoryUsage[temp] = old.memoryUsage();
   }
   /// old.UpdatecpuUsage();
    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, MAX_PATH)) {
      HICON icon = ExtractIcon((HINSTANCE)hProcess, szProcessName, 0);
      if (icon) {
        old.SetIcon(QIcon(QtWin::fromHICON(icon)));
      } else {
        icon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
        old.SetIcon(QIcon(QtWin::fromHICON(icon)));
      }
      DestroyIcon(icon);
    }

  } else {
    old.Setname("<NULL>");
  }


  // Release the handle to the process.

  CloseHandle(hProcess);
}


auto MainWindow::updateProcessInfo() {

  DWORD aProcesses[1024]; DWORD cbNeeded; DWORD cProcesses;
  unsigned int i;

  if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded)) {
    qWarning() << "Error could not enumerate processes\n";
  }

  // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
  cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
  auto &processes = device_processes;
  std::map<int, Process> pmap;

  if (processes.empty()) {
    processes.resize(cProcesses);
    processes.fill(Process(), processes.size());
  } else {
    processes.resize(cProcesses);
  }

  int k = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++) {
    getProcessInfo(aProcesses[i], processes[k]);
    if (processes[k].memoryUsage() != 0 && processes[k].name() != "<unknown>" &&
        processes[k].name() != "<NULL>") {
      k++;
    }
  }

  processes.resize(k);
  for (const auto& process : processes) {
    pmap[process.Id()] = process;
  }

    
  QVector<Process> newProcesses;
  // a way to avoid using push_back()
  i = 0;
  for (const auto& j : pmap) {

    if (j.second.child()!=1) {
      newProcesses.append(j.second);
    }
    i++;
  }

  device_processes = newProcesses;
}

void MainWindow::updateProcessInfoTree() {

  // only update every 500 milliseconds and if the current tab is the tables



  if (clocks % 500 == 0 && ui->tabWidget->currentIndex() != 0) {
    updateProcessInfo();
    int len = device_processes.size();
    int len2 = processInfoTree->topLevelItemCount();
    int len3 = len - len2;
    /*add or remove items based off new length*/
    if (len3 > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < len3; i++) {
        new QTreeWidgetItem(
            processInfoTree, QStringList{" ", " ", " ", " "});
      }
    } else if (len3 < 0) {
      for (int i = len2 - 1; i > (len2 - 1) - abs(len3); --i) {
        delete processInfoTree->takeTopLevelItem(i);
      }
    }
    auto sorted_device_processes = device_processes;
    /*Sort table based on current sort mode*/
    switch (currentSortMode) {

    default:
      break;
    case SortMode::NameSortAZ:
      std::sort(
          sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
          [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool { return a.name() < b.name(); });
      break;
    case SortMode::NameSortZA:
      std::sort(
          sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
          [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool { return a.name() > b.name(); });
      break;
    case CpuSortAZ:
      std::sort(sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
                [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool {
                  return a.cpuUsage() < b.cpuUsage();
                });
      break;
    case CpuSortZA:
      std::sort(sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
                [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool {
                  return a.cpuUsage() > b.cpuUsage();
                });
      break;
    case MemorySortAZ:
      std::sort(sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
                [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool {
                  return a.memoryUsage() < b.memoryUsage();
                });
      break;
    case MemorySortZA:
      std::sort(sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
                [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool {
                  return a.memoryUsage() > b.memoryUsage();
                });
      break;
    case ProcessIDSortAZ:
      std::sort(sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
                [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool { return a.Id() < b.Id(); });
      break;
    case ProcessIDSortZA:
      std::sort(sorted_device_processes.begin(), sorted_device_processes.end(),
                [](Process &a, Process &b) -> bool { return a.Id() > b.Id(); });
      break;
    case NoSort:
      break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

      auto process = sorted_device_processes[i];

      QTreeWidgetItem item5;

      QStringList currentRow(QString(process.name()));
      currentRow.append(QString::number(process.memoryUsage()) + "Mb");
      currentRow.append(QString::number(process.cpuUsage()) + "%");
      currentRow.append(QString::number(process.Id()));
      item5 = QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget *)nullptr, currentRow);

      item5.setIcon(0, process.icon());
      // update item at index i in the tree
      *processInfoTree->topLevelItem(i) = item5;
      processInfoTree->topLevelItem(i)->takeChildren();
      for (const auto& child : process.children()) {

        QStringList currentChildRow(QString(child.name()));
        currentChildRow.append(QString::number(child.memoryUsage()) + "Mb");
        currentChildRow.append(QString::number(child.cpuUsage()) + "%");
        currentChildRow.append(QString::number(child.Id()));
        auto *item6 =
            new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget *)nullptr, currentChildRow);
        item6->setIcon(0, child.icon());
        processInfoTree->topLevelItem(i)->addChild(item6);
      }
    }
    //update process combo box
    updateProcessComboBox();
  }
}

void MainWindow::updateProcessComboBox()
{
    int numberOfProcesses = device_processes.size();
    int len = numberOfProcesses;
    int len2 = process_ComboBox->count();
    int len3 = len - len2;
    /*add or remove items based off new length*/
    if (len3 > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < len3; i++) {
        process_ComboBox->addItem("");
      }
    } else if (len3 < 0) {
      for (int i = len2 - 1; i > (len2 - 1) - abs(len3); --i) {
          process_ComboBox->removeItem(i);
      }
    }

    for(auto i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; ++i)
    {
        process_ComboBox->setItemText(i,device_processes[i].name());
    }
  int currentProcessIndex = process_ComboBox->findText(currentProcess.name());
  if(currentProcessIndex^-1)//if it finds the currentProcess
  {
    process_ComboBox->setCurrentIndex(currentProcessIndex);
  }



}

void MainWindow::get_cpuClock(std::byte *currentValue) {

  double sample = 0;

  if (clocks % cpu_SamplingRate == 0) {

    sample = GetCPULoad() * 100.0;
    if (clocks % 2 == 0) {
      if (currentValue != nullptr) {
        *currentValue = static_cast<std::byte>(sample);
      }
      add_sample(device_samples[1], sample);
    }

  }
}
void MainWindow::getProcess_cpuClock(std::byte *currentValue)
{
    double sample = 0;
    if(device_processes.empty()){return;}

    if (clocks % cpu_SamplingRate == 0) {
      sample = currentProcess.cpuUsage() * 100.0;
      if (clocks % 2 == 0) {
        if (currentValue != nullptr) {
          *currentValue = static_cast<std::byte>(sample);
        }
        add_sample(process_samples[1], sample);
      }
    }
}

void MainWindow::Update() {
    //increment clock
  clocks++;
  get_cpuClock((current_device == Cpu) ? &currentResourceUsage : nullptr);

  get_mem((current_device == Memory) ? &currentResourceUsage : nullptr);

  // if stayOnTop is enabled make the window Stay on Top
  if (stayOnTop == 0) {
    stayOnTop = 2;
    setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint |
                   Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

  } else if (stayOnTop == 1) {
    stayOnTop = 2;
    this->setWindowFlags((this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint) &
                         ~Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);
  }



  // update tree and graph
  updateProcessInfoTree();
  processResource();




getProcess_cpuClock(nullptr);

getProcess_mem(nullptr);


//update the current process from process_ComboBox
currentProcess = device_processes[std::max(0,process_ComboBox->currentIndex())];
getProcessInfo(currentProcess.Id(),currentProcess);




 
  if (!selectedItemsInUse) {
    selectedItems = processInfoTree->selectedItems();
  }





  // draw/hide button based off conditions
  switch(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()){
  case 0:{
    ui->pushButton_2->hide();
    ui->comboBox_2->hide();
    break;
  } case 1:{
    ui->pushButton_2->show();
    ui->comboBox_2->hide();
    break;
  }
  case 2:{
      ui->comboBox_2->show();
      ui->pushButton_2->hide();
      break;
  }
}




  // update every millisecond
  QTimer::singleShot(1, this, SLOT(Update()));
}
void MainWindow::do_test() {
  static std::vector<char> alloc;
  static QElapsedTimer __timer;
 long double time = __timer.nsecsElapsed()/(long double)(1e9);
long double mema = sinl(time)*0.5l+0.5l;
  mema *= mb*512.;
  //qWarning() << mema << '\n';
 alloc.resize(mema);
}

void MainWindow::processResource() {

  GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);

  // redraw everytime update is called;
  resourceUsageLabel->setText(
      QString::number((unsigned char)currentResourceUsage) + "%");

  // process resource use
  switch (current_device) {
  case Memory: {

    draw(static_cast<double>(total_ram) / gb, Memory);

    if(device_processes.empty() ||  ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()^2) {return;}


    processDraw(processMax_MemoryUsage[currentProcess.name()]
            , Memory);

    break;
  }

  case Cpu: {

    draw(100.0, Cpu);
    if(device_processes.empty() ||  ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()^2) {return;}
    processDraw(100.0, Cpu);
    break;
  }
  }
}

double MainWindow::get_mem_val() {
  double sample = 0;

  GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);

  sample = double(total_ram - (long long)statex.ullAvailPhys) / gb;
  return sample;
}

void MainWindow::reset_sampleRate(Computer_device type) {

  int temp_rate = (type == Memory) ? mem_sampleRate : cpu_sampleRate;

  x = QVector<double>(temp_rate, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < temp_rate; ++i) {
    x[i] = ((double)i / (temp_rate));
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1) {

  // Memory

  if (arg1 == "Memory") {

    reset_sampleRate(Memory);
    ui->label->setText("Memory Usage");

    current_device = Memory;
  }

  if (arg1 == "Cpu") {

    reset_sampleRate(Cpu);
    device_samples[1].fill(GetCPULoad() * 100.0, cpu_sampleRate);

    ui->label->setText("Cpu Usage");

    current_device = Cpu;
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionStay_on_top_triggered() {}

void MainWindow::on_actionStay_on_top_toggled(bool arg1) {
  stayOnTop = (arg1) ? 0 : 1;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
  imageIsSafe = true;

  switch (ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()) {
  case 0: {
    capture_plot = true;
    break;
  }
  case 1: {

    break;
  }

  default:
    break;
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionSave_as_triggered() {
  if (imageIsSafe) {
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(
        this, tr("Save Image File"), QString(), tr("Images (*.png)"));
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
      m_plot.save(fileName);
    }
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked() {
  selectedItemsInUse = true;
  if (selectedItems.empty()) {
    return;
  }
  std::vector<size_t> processIds(selectedItems.size());
  int i = 0;
  for (const QTreeWidgetItem *treeItem : selectedItems) {
    // if item selected is not a process id column continue
    processIds[i] = treeItem->text(3).toULongLong();
    i++;
  }
  // delete all the selected process
  i = 0;
  for (const auto &processId : processIds) {
    /*magic WIN32 API stuff*/
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);
    if (nullptr != hProcess) {

      if (processId == GetCurrentProcessId()) {
#if 0
          int  k;
          int start = QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay();
                float A =
                    0, B = 0, i, j, z[1760]; char b[
                        1760]; printf("\x1b[2J"); for (;;
                            ) {
                            this->setWindowOpacity(1.0f/((QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay()-start) / 1000.0f));
                            memset(b, 32, 1760); memset(z, 0, 7040)
                                ; for (j = 0; 6.28 > j; j += 0.07)for (i = 0; 6.28
 > i; i += 0.02) {
                                float c = sin(i), d = cos(j), e =
                                    sin(A), f = sin(j), g = cos(A), h = d + 2, D = 1 / (c *
                                        h * e + f * g + 5), l = cos(i), m = cos(B), n = sin(B), t = c * h * g - f * e; int x = 40 + 30 * D *
                                    (l * h * m - t * n), y = 12 + 15 * D * (l * h * n
                                        + t * m), o = x + 80 * y, N = 8 * ((f * e - c * d * g
                                            ) * m - c * d * e - f * g - l * d * n); if (22 > y &&
                                                y > 0 && x > 0 && 80 > x && D > z[o]) {
                                    z[o] = D;;; b[o] =
                                        ".,-~:;=!*#$@"[N > 0 ? N : 0];
                                }
                            }/*#****!!-*/
                            printf("\x1b[H"); for (k = 0; 1761 > k; k++)
                                putchar(k % 80 ? b[k] : 10); A += 0.04; B +=
                                0.02;
                        }
            /*****####*******!!=;:~
                  ~::==!!!**********!!!==::-
                    .,~~;;;========;;;:~-.
                        ..,--------,*/
#else
        int start = QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay();
        float currentTime =
            ((QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay() - start) / 1000.0F);
        while (1.0F / currentTime >= 1.0F / 5.0F)
          this->setWindowOpacity(1.0F / (currentTime)),
              currentTime =
                  ((QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay() - start) /
                   1000.0F);
#endif
      }
      // use WaitForSingleObject to make sure it's dead
      if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)) {
        qWarning() << "Error could not terminate process\n";
      }

      CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

    processInfoTree->takeTopLevelItem(
        processInfoTree->indexOfTopLevelItem(selectedItems.at(i)));
    processIds.erase(processIds.begin());
    i++;
  }
  selectedItems.clear();
  selectedItemsInUse = false;
}

void MainWindow::tableHeader_clicked(int column) {
  /*a way to avoid using modulus*/
  struct num {
    unsigned char t : 1;
  };
  static num clicks[4]{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};

  currentSortMode = static_cast<SortMode>(column + clicks[column].t * 4);
  clicks[column] = num{static_cast<unsigned char>(clicks[column].t + 1)};
}
```

Processitem.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QString>
#include <cstdint>
#include<qicon.h>
#include <windows.h>
class Process
{
protected:
    //process name
    QString _name = "";
    //process id
    uint64_t _Id = 0;

    double _memoryUsage = 0;

    double _cpuUsage = 0;
    QIcon _icon;    
    bool _child = false;
    std::vector<Process> _children;



public:
    Process();
    Process(const QString& name, const uint64_t& Id, const double& memoryUsage,const double& cpuUsage,const QIcon& icon,bool child = false);

    QString name() const;
    //process id
    uint64_t Id() const;

    double memoryUsage() const;
    double cpuUsage() const;

    QIcon icon()const;
    bool child() const;
    void Setname(const QString& name);
    void UpdatecpuUsage();
    void SetId(const uint64_t& Id);

    void SetmemoryUsage(const double& memoryUsage);

    void SetcpuUsage(const double& cpuUsage);
    void SetIcon(const QIcon& icon);
    void SetChild(const bool& child);
    void addChild(Process child);
    std::vector<Process> children();
};
```

ProcessItem.cpp

```
#include "Processitem.h"
Process::Process()
{
    children() = std::vector<Process>();
};

Process::Process(const QString& name, const uint64_t& Id, const double& memoryUsage,const double& cpuUsage,const QIcon& icon,bool child)
{
    if (_name = name, _Id = Id, _memoryUsage = memoryUsage,_icon=icon,_child = child, _cpuUsage = cpuUsage) { }
}

QString Process::name() const
{
    return _name;
}

uint64_t Process::Id() const
{
    return _Id;
}

double Process::memoryUsage() const
{

    return _memoryUsage;
}

double Process::cpuUsage() const
{
    return _cpuUsage;
}

QIcon Process::icon() const
{
    return _icon;
}

bool Process::child() const
{
    return _child;
}

void Process::Setname(const QString& name)
{
    _name = name;
}

void Process::SetId(const uint64_t& Id)
{
    _Id = Id;
}

void Process::SetmemoryUsage(const double& memoryUsage)
{
    _memoryUsage = memoryUsage;
}

void Process::SetcpuUsage(const double& cpuUsage)
{
    _cpuUsage = cpuUsage;
}

void Process::UpdatecpuUsage()
{
 /*
    if constexpr (true) {
        QString  temp = "\\Process(";
        auto tempName = _name;
        temp += tempName.remove(".exe") + ")";
        temp += "\\% Processor Time";
        std::cout << temp.toStdString() << '\n';
        _Cpu = std::make_shared<PdhCPUCounter>(PdhCPUCounter{ temp.toStdString() });
    }
_cpuUsage = _Cpu->getCPUUtilization();
*/
}

void Process::SetIcon(const QIcon &icon)
{
    _icon=icon;
}

void Process::SetChild(const bool& child)
{
    _child = child;
}

void Process::addChild(Process child)
{
    _children.push_back(child);
}

std::vector<Process> Process::children()
{
    return _children;
}
```

ui_mainwindow.h

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'mainwindow.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.12.5
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QComboBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QTabWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QTreeWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <qcustomplot.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QAction *actionSave_as;
    QAction *actionStay_on_top;
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout_6;
    QPushButton *pushButton_2;
    QLabel *label_2;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout_2;
    QTabWidget *tabWidget;
    QCustomPlot *tab;
    QWidget *tab_2;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout_4;
    QTreeWidget *treeWidget;
    QCustomPlot *tab_3;
    QLabel *label;
    QComboBox *comboBox;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout_3;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QComboBox *comboBox_2;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_2;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_2;
    QStatusBar *statusbar;
    QMenuBar *menubar;
    QMenu *menuFile;
    QMenu *menuView;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(804, 600);
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        MainWindow->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        MainWindow->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8(""));
        actionSave_as = new QAction(MainWindow);
        actionSave_as->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionSave_as"));
        actionStay_on_top = new QAction(MainWindow);
        actionStay_on_top->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionStay_on_top"));
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
        centralwidget->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8(""));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(centralwidget);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        gridLayout_6 = new QGridLayout();
        gridLayout_6->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout_6"));
        pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(centralwidget);
        pushButton_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton_2"));
        pushButton_2->setEnabled(true);
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy1(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(pushButton_2->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        pushButton_2->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);

        gridLayout_6->addWidget(pushButton_2, 8, 1, 1, 1, Qt::AlignBottom);

        label_2 = new QLabel(centralwidget);
        label_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_2"));
        QFont font;
        font.setFamily(QString::fromUtf8("Segoe UI Semibold"));
        font.setPointSize(29);
        label_2->setFont(font);

        gridLayout_6->addWidget(label_2, 8, 0, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(16, 22, QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout_6->addItem(horizontalSpacer, 8, 2, 1, 1);


        gridLayout->addLayout(gridLayout_6, 2, 0, 2, 1);

        gridLayout_2 = new QGridLayout();
        gridLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"));
        gridLayout_2->setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 1);
        tabWidget = new QTabWidget(centralwidget);
        tabWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tabWidget"));
        tab = new QCustomPlot();
        tab->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tab"));
        tabWidget->addTab(tab, QString());
        tab_2 = new QWidget();
        tab_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tab_2"));
        gridLayout_4 = new QGridLayout(tab_2);
        gridLayout_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout_4"));
        treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(tab_2);
        new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
        treeWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("treeWidget"));

        gridLayout_4->addWidget(treeWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        tabWidget->addTab(tab_2, QString());
        tab_3 = new QCustomPlot();
        tab_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tab_3"));
        tabWidget->addTab(tab_3, QString());

        gridLayout_2->addWidget(tabWidget, 0, 1, 1, 1);


        gridLayout->addLayout(gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        label = new QLabel(centralwidget);
        label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy2(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
        sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy2.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(label->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        label->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2);
        QFont font1;
        font1.setFamily(QString::fromUtf8("Segoe UI Semibold"));
        font1.setPointSize(18);
        font1.setBold(false);
        font1.setWeight(50);
        label->setFont(font1);
        label->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("QLabel{\n"
"\n"
"color: rgb(42, 42, 42)\n"
"\n"
"}"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(label, 2, 3, 1, 1);

        comboBox = new QComboBox(centralwidget);
        comboBox->addItem(QString());
        comboBox->addItem(QString());
        comboBox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("comboBox"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy3(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        sizePolicy3.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy3.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy3.setHeightForWidth(comboBox->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        comboBox->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy3);

        gridLayout->addWidget(comboBox, 3, 3, 1, 1);

        gridLayout_3 = new QGridLayout();
        gridLayout_3->setSpacing(6);
        gridLayout_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout_3"));
        gridLayout_3->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pushButton = new QPushButton(centralwidget);
        pushButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton"));
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(pushButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        pushButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2);
        pushButton->setFlat(false);

        gridLayout_3->addWidget(pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        comboBox_2 = new QComboBox(centralwidget);
        comboBox_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("comboBox_2"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy4(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
        sizePolicy4.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy4.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy4.setHeightForWidth(comboBox_2->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        comboBox_2->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy4);
        comboBox_2->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0));

        gridLayout_3->addWidget(comboBox_2, 7, 0, 1, 3);

        verticalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        gridLayout_3->addItem(verticalSpacer, 3, 1, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout_3->addItem(horizontalSpacer_2, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        verticalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(21, 182, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);

        gridLayout_3->addItem(verticalSpacer_2, 8, 1, 1, 1);


        gridLayout->addLayout(gridLayout_3, 0, 3, 1, 1);

        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
        statusbar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusbar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusbar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusbar);
        menubar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menubar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menubar"));
        menubar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 804, 25));
        menuFile = new QMenu(menubar);
        menuFile->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuFile"));
        menuView = new QMenu(menubar);
        menuView->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuView"));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menubar);

        menubar->addAction(menuFile->menuAction());
        menubar->addAction(menuView->menuAction());
        menuFile->addAction(actionSave_as);
        menuView->addAction(actionStay_on_top);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(2);


        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", nullptr));
        actionSave_as->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Save as", nullptr));
        actionStay_on_top->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Stay on top", nullptr));
        pushButton_2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "End Task", nullptr));
        label_2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "0%", nullptr));
        tabWidget->setTabText(tabWidget->indexOf(tab), QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1", nullptr));
        QTreeWidgetItem *___qtreewidgetitem = treeWidget->headerItem();
        ___qtreewidgetitem->setText(0, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "1", nullptr));

        const bool __sortingEnabled = treeWidget->isSortingEnabled();
        treeWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
        QTreeWidgetItem *___qtreewidgetitem1 = treeWidget->topLevelItem(0);
        ___qtreewidgetitem1->setText(0, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "New Item", nullptr));
        treeWidget->setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled);

        tabWidget->setTabText(tabWidget->indexOf(tab_2), QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Page", nullptr));
        tabWidget->setTabText(tabWidget->indexOf(tab_3), QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Page", nullptr));
        label->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Memory Usage", nullptr));
        comboBox->setItemText(0, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Memory", nullptr));
        comboBox->setItemText(1, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Cpu", nullptr));

        pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "ScreenShot", nullptr));
        menuFile->setTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "File", nullptr));
        menuView->setTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "View", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include<windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Task Manager");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The qcustomplot files are too big to put here so they can be downloaded from here https://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General impression

The indentation and spacing are inconsistent.  Fix them.  Remove gratuitous blocks of several blank lines.

Compare your code formatting to the auto-generated files.  There's a huge difference.

## Include guards

Sometimes you use `#pragma once`, and sometimes `#ifndef`.  Pick one and use it consistently.

## Preprocessor directives

This is a mess:

> ```
> #include <QMainWindow>
> #include <QWidget>
> #include <QEvent>
> #include "qcustomplot.h"
> #include <QElapsedTimer>
> #include <chrono>
> #include <thread>
> #include <QString>
> #include "Processitem.h"
> #include <cstddef>
> #define _WIN32_DCOM
> #include<windows.h>
> #include<memory>
> ```

Sort them by some clear metric and add blank lines; for example:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QWidget>

#include "Processitem.h"
#include "qcustomplot.h"
```

## Dealing with bytes

> ```
> #define gb (1024.0*1024.0*1024.0)
> #define mb (1024.0*1024.0)
> #define kb (1024.0)
> ```

Use `constexpr` variables instead of macros:

```
constexpr double gb = 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0;
constexpr double mb = 1024.0 * 1024.0;
constexpr double kb = 1024.0;
```

However, a better alternative is to introduce types to clearly indicate intent and prevent errors, similar to how [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) handles time:

```
template <typename Rep, typename Ratio = std::ratio<1>>
class memory_size {
public:
    using rep = Rep;
    using ratio = typename Ratio::type; // number of bytes in a unit

    // ...
};

using gibi = std::ratio<1024 * 1024 * 1024>;
using mebi = std::ratio<1024 * 1024>;
using kibi = std::ratio<1024>;

using gibibytes = memory_size<double, gibi>;
using mebibytes = memory_size<double, mebi>;
using kibibytes = memory_size<double, kibi>;

namespace literals {
    constexpr auto operator""_gb(long double units) noexcept
    {
        return gibibytes{units};
    }
    constexpr auto operator""_kb(long double units) noexcept
    {
        return mebibytes{units};
    }
    constexpr auto operator""_mb(long double units) noexcept
    {
        return kibibytes{units};
    }
}
```

## `MainWindow`

The class is ... unintelligible.

The members are scattering all around the class.  Put them in one place.  But do you really need so many members?

There is a lot of `new` in your code.  `new` shouldn't occur so much in application code.  Most of the pointers should be changed to normal variables instead.  Then, the destructor can be removed.

To be honest, I don't understand most of the implementation, so I can't comment.

## Conclusion

I realize that reviewing further is useless after seeing trolling code like this:

```
#if 0
          int  k;
          int start = QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay();
                float A =
                    0, B = 0, i, j, z[1760]; char b[
                        1760]; printf("\x1b[2J"); for (;;
                            ) {
                            this->setWindowOpacity(1.0f/((QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay()-start) / 1000.0f));
                            memset(b, 32, 1760); memset(z, 0, 7040)
                                ; for (j = 0; 6.28 > j; j += 0.07)for (i = 0; 6.28
 > i; i += 0.02) {
                                float c = sin(i), d = cos(j), e =
                                    sin(A), f = sin(j), g = cos(A), h = d + 2, D = 1 / (c *
                                        h * e + f * g + 5), l = cos(i), m = cos(B), n = sin(B), t = c * h * g - f * e; int x = 40 + 30 * D *
                                    (l * h * m - t * n), y = 12 + 15 * D * (l * h * n
                                        + t * m), o = x + 80 * y, N = 8 * ((f * e - c * d * g
                                            ) * m - c * d * e - f * g - l * d * n); if (22 > y &&
                                                y > 0 && x > 0 && 80 > x && D > z[o]) {
                                    z[o] = D;;; b[o] =
                                        ".,-~:;=!*#$@"[N > 0 ? N : 0];
                                }
                            }/*#****!!-*/
                            printf("\x1b[H"); for (k = 0; 1761 > k; k++)
                                putchar(k % 80 ? b[k] : 10); A += 0.04; B +=
                                0.02;
                        }
            /*****####*******!!=;:~
                  ~::==!!!**********!!!==::-
                    .,~~;;;========;;;:~-.
                        ..,--------,*/
#else
```